# Aplicação Aspnet Core 6.0 MVC retornando erro invalid_request invalid redirect_uri com duende IdentityServer 6

Tags: c#, mvc, asp-net-core

Olá! Estou enfrentando o seguinte problema na minha aplicação. São três projetos na solução: Um WebApp MVC, uma WebApi MVC e um IdentityServer com Duende. A aplicação roda perfeitamente em localhost, somente na hospedagem tá ocorrendo o erro da imagem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ioh5B.png

> Sorry, there was an error : invalid_request
> Invalid redirect_uri
> Request Id: 0HMVV0QSC89KD:00000021

Seguem os códigos...
Projeto: RGShopWeb

```
Program.cs
```

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
    .AddCookie("Cookies", c =>
    {
        c.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        c.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
        {
            OnRedirectToAccessDenied = (context) =>
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(builder.Configuration["ServiceUri:IdentityServer"] + "/Account/AccessDenied");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    })

    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = context =>
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/");
            context.HandleResponse();

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        };

        options.Authority = builder.Configuration["ServiceUri:IdentityServer"];
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.ClientId = "rgshop";
        options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Client:Secret"];
        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role", "role");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("sub", "sub", "sub");
        options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
        options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
        options.Scope.Add("rgshop");
        options.SaveTokens = true;
    }
    );
```

```
appSettings.json
```

```
   {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ServiceUri": {
    "ProductApi": "https://rgshopapi.somee.com",
    "IdentityServer": "https://rgshopidentityserver.somee.com"
  },
  "Client": {
    "Secret": "***" //chave secreta
  }
}
```

```
RGShopWeb.csproj
```

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.0.25" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.33.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Projeto IdentityServer

```
RGShop.IdentityServer.csproj
```

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Duende.IdentityServer.AspNetIdentity" Version="6.3.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.25" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="6.0.25" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.25">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.25" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

```
appSettings.json
```

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=RGShopDB.mssql.somee.com;Packet Size=4096;Database=RGShopDB;User Id=***;Password=***;Trusted_Connection=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;Persist Security Info=False"
    //"DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost,1433;Database=RGShopDB;User Id=sa;Password=***;Trusted_Connection=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

```
IdentityConfiguration.cs
```

```
using Duende.IdentityServer;
using Duende.IdentityServer.Models;

namespace RGShop.IdentityServer.Configuration;

public class IdentityConfiguration
{
    public const string Admin = "Admin";
    public const string Client = "Client";

    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
        new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Email(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile()
        };

    public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
        new List<ApiScope>
        {
            new ApiScope("rgshop", "RGShop Server"),
            new ApiScope(name: "read", "Read data."),
            new ApiScope(name: "write", "Write data."),
            new ApiScope(name: "delete", "Delete data."),
        };

    public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
        new List<Client>
        {
            //client genérico
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "client",
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret("***".Sha256())},
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                AllowedScopes = {"read", "write", "profile" }
            },
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "rgshop",
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret("***".Sha256())},
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                //RedirectUris = {"https://localhost:7286/signin-oidc"},
                RedirectUris = {"https://rgshopweb.somee.com/signin-oidc", "https://rgshopidentityserver.somee.com"},
                //PostLogoutRedirectUris = {"https://localhost:7286/signout-callback-oidc"},
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = {"https://rgshopweb.somee.com/signout-callback-oidc"},
                AllowedCorsOrigins = {"https://rgshopweb.somee.com","https://rgshopidentityserver.somee.com"},
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                    "rgshop"
                }
            }
        };       
}
```